# ResultSet destroyed upon ObjectOutputStream .reset()

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset, objectoutputstream

the code:

```
    Connection connection;
    String url, usernameDB, passwordDB;

    url = "...";
    usernameDB = "...";
    passwordDB = "..."; 

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usernameDB, passwordDB);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    queryResult = statement.executeQuery(query); 
    boolean moreRecords = queryResult.next();
    if(!moreRecords)
    {
        out.writeBoolean(false);
        out.flush();
    }
    else
    {
        int cols=0;
        out.writeBoolean(true);
        out.flush();
        out.reset(); // line 1
        cols = queryResult.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        out.writeInt(cols);
        out.flush();
        out.reset(); 
        out.flush();
        out.reset();
        do
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
            {
                out.writeObject(queryResult.getObject(i)); // line 2
                out.flush();
                out.reset();
            }
            out.writeBoolean(false);
            out.flush();
            out.reset();
        }
        while(queryResult.next());
    }
```

'out' is an ObjectOutputStream.

When i get to line 1 in the code above, the queryResult object resets itself, and when i come to line 2 i get an exception:

> "java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set".

I have tried to find a way to increase the timeout of the connection, but found no way.
it seems that when I get to line 1 in the code above I lose my connection to the database, thus destroying my queryResult object.

Is there a way to solve this, or maybe clone the result set (with it's values)?

**EDIT**

this code runs in tomcat 6, i open a ServerSocket and for each connection i start a new thread which in turn performs the code above....

Comment: Any operation on an `ObjectOutputStream` will have no effect on a `java.sql.ResultSet`.  Therefore, there must be some code you haven't posted.

Comment: but that is my problem, that the ObjectOutStream DOES have an effect on the ResultSet....
the only thing that i can think of is that this code runs in a thread....

Answer (score 0):

after some research, i found a solution.

i use a `CachedRowset` object to hold a copy from the ResultSet with all its values.

this is the code after the change:

```
CachedRowSet cachedResults = new CachedRowSetImpl();

queryResult = statement.executeQuery(query);
cachedResults.populate(queryResult); // this is important!!
boolean moreRecords = cachedResults.next();
if(!moreRecords)
{
    out.writeBoolean(false);
    out.flush();
}
else
{
    int cols=0;
    out.writeBoolean(true);
    out.flush();
    cols = cachedResults.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    out.writeInt(cols);
    out.flush();
    do
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
        {
            out.writeObject(cachedResults.getObject(i));
            out.flush();
        }
                    out.writeBoolean(false);
        out.flush();
    }
    while(cachedResults.next());
}
```